# Using same image map on multiple images but with a different link for each area on each image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to use multiple images using the image map "imageTileMap".

```
<map name="imageTileMap">
    <area id="quiz"shape="circle" coords="41,193,20" href="">
    <area id="video"shape="circle" coords="112,193,20" href="">
    <area id="presentation"shape="circle" coords="184,193,20" href="">
</map>
```

And I am using Javascript so that each area links to an anchor on a separate page, the page being dependent on the image itself. My function is:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeLink(clicked_href) {
    var url = clicked_href;  
    var areaQuiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
areaQuiz.href = url + "#quiz";

var areaVideo = document.getElementById("video");
areaVideo.href = url + "#video";

var areaPresentation = document.getElementById("presentation");
areaPresentation.href = url + "#presentation";
  }
  </script>
```

And the first image itself is set up as so:

```
<a id="firstImage" href="linkedPage1.html"><img src="image1.png" usemap="#imageTileMap" onClick="changeLink(this.href)"/></a>
```

The second image is formatted as:

```
 <a id="secondImage" href="linkedPage2.html"><img src="image2.png" usemap="#imageTileMap" onClick="changeLink(this.href)"/></a>
```

The problem that I have currently is that clicking on any <area> on the first image directs me towards the anchor of the second image's href. How can I change the changeLink function to correctly collect the correct href? I am grateful for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Everything remain same ,,, Just change Image Code....Href set to same page as from it clicked

Change the first image Code to:

```
<a id="firstImage" href="linkedPage2.html"><img src="image1.png" usemap="#imageTileMap" onClick="changeLink(this.href)"/></a>
```

Do Same as first:

```
 <a id="secondImage" href="linkedPage1.html"><img src="image2.png" usemap="#imageTileMap" onClick="changeLink(this.href)"/></a>
```

Comment: I could use this method but I am looking for a way to apply the same image map to all images. I have many images so applying a unique image map to each would be inefficient.